# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am experiencing a `BeanDefinitionStoreException` when I try to run a web app that I built using `Spring` and `gradle`.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'transactionApi' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/api-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'wu.enrollment.time' in string value [${wu.enrollment.time}]
```

Comment: And what did you not understand in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your bean transactionApi is expecting a property to be set using Spring's replaceable properties. The error tells you the replaceable property is wu.enrollment.time.  See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) for Spring's documentation on how it works.